# Selecting a column (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

```
$('.table tbody td:eq(3)').addClass('col4');
```

..works, but only selects the first cell, not all cells in the column.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".table tbody td:nth-child(4)").addClass("col4");
```

**Note:** I've put 4 here because [`:eq(n)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq#index) is zero-based and [`:nth-child(n)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild) is one-based.

You've stumbled on the key difference between the two. `eq(3)` will return exactly one element, the 4th from the *entire* set. Much like how [`:first`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/first) only returns one element (max) whereas [`:first-child`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/firstChild) can return many.

Comment: Perrrrrrrrrfect! :) (Sorry, SO won't allow less than 15 chars)

Comment: This also demonstrates why jQuery's `:eq` selector should be viewed with suspicion. It applies not to the selector-part in context like every other :psuedo-class selector, but to the selector in its entirity. Since it is not a standard CSS selector it also forces use of the Sizzle library instead of the fast `querySelectorAll` implementation in newer browsers. Where you need this functionality, avoid the `:eq` selector; use `.eq()` on the results instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `<col>` element to style whole columns instead of having to apply styles to all `<td>`s in that column.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4.2

Comment: I don't think you can do much with <col>, it doesn't allow CSS styling I guess?

Comment: It does, but only allows a few styles. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html

Comment: That quirksmode site didn't work for me.  [Here's its latest working archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905105008/http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/columns.html).

Comment: The [CSS 2.1 docs on table columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns) state that you can do this _only_ for `border`, `background`, `width`, and `visibility` (and all of their parts, e.g. `border-style`), though the example actually notes using `table-layout`, so that's likely an incomplete list.  You certainly _can't_ cascade, e.g. `col:hover td { background:red }` :-(